# regular expression to detect mentions but not detecting emails

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code:

```
preg_match('/@([^@ ]+)/', $image->caption->text, $matches)
```

and I wanted to basically detect mentions in a string. However the issue now is that it is confused with email address such that it detects email as a mention, so for example if I have `aksdjasd@yahoo.com` then this counts as a match. I guess what I want to say here is that before the @ sign there should be a space. But how do I put that in to this regex?

**EDIT:**
I also wanted to detect @mentions at the beginning of the string as well

Comment: You guys are too shy of corner cases. @adit already accepted the beginning of line. I would say @anubhava still has 4 problems to fix: `(@foo nice try)@adit good " @" [bad @]`. Try that in his working demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> before the @ sign there should be a space

You can use lookbehind (edited based on OP's comment below):

```
preg_match('/(?<= |^)@[^@ ]+/', $image->caption->text, $matches);
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/lB6kB5)

Comment: Neither of our answers detect mentions at the VERY beginning of a string as the first thing in it, since the positive look behind fails.

Comment: @Walls: I intentionally didn't allow for that as OP clearly wrote: `before the @ sign there should be a space`

Comment: I think there are a few issues with the original regex other then just the "before space" part.  I just wanted to let it be known that there are some weird interactions with what was asked for, and what I think the OP is looking for.  Specifically looking for mentions (Twitter for example) could have strings/mentions starting with the tag the user is hunting for.

Comment: Not good enough for me, either. `preg_match('/(?<= )@([^@ ]+)/', "Easy? No.@anubhava try harder! @\t", $matches2); //this will only recognize the (invalid) tab.`

Comment: @Walls that's actually a good point, I actually wanted to detect mentions at the beginning of the string as well

Comment: @MadaaKaama's answer handles mentions at the beginning of the string, as well as some of the other things I was mentioning/worrying about with just using spaces.  My answer handles them, but is not as robust at handling some of the more crazy cases.

Answer (score 1):

My take:

```
preg_match('/(?<=\W|^)@(\w+)/', "@Easy? No.@anubhava try harder! @\t", $matches);
preg_match('/(?<=\W|^)@(\w+)/', "Easy? No.@anubhava try harder! @\t", $matches);
preg_match('/(?<=\W|^)@(\w+)/', "Easy? No.anubhava try harder! e@m @\t", $match);
```

Correctly recognizes *@Easy* , *@anubhava* and not the tab or email.

Answer (score 0):

You can use look behinds to check behind your regex.

Try using: `preg_match('/(?<![^\s])@([^@\s]+)/', $image->caption->text, $matches);`

Important thing to note here, is that you also want to use `\s` in the class you check for AFTER the `@`.  If not, you could end up matching `@stuff<NEWLINE><nonmatch>`.  I did some quick testing and found the problems with just using space for a number of reasons.  [Here is a link to the tests](http://rubular.com/r/NthScUPdIo).

This is also using a negative look behind, because if the mention is at the front of the string it would not match using a positive look behind.  You have to account for blank in front of the positive matches.

I think just checking for a space alone could have risks.  I think you might want to check for any whitespace character, just in case the mention is at the very beginning of the string.

Comment: Try this: '@first @second email@domain.com@rubbish Yep.@Other reference \'@\' "@" tricky@'

Comment: Seems to only be matching `@first` and `@second`.  The issue is that checking for an "email" simply by making sure there is nothing before an @ symbol is weak, especially since validating emails using regex alone can be a tricky beast.  You in theory could add more things to the negative look behind to account for bad punctuation.  For example, if you want to capture the `@Other` after the period, add a period into the negative look behind (double negative :) ).