# Find word that does not come after word with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to get all the text which start with **@** and replace them with the needed text

here's it's regex

```
/@([a-z_\d]+)/gi
```

Now the issue I'm facing is I just wanted to get the text if it's alone like

**example: hey @hasham my email is vakanihasham@gmail.com**

When I run the regex, it should provide me with the @hasham value but not the @gmail. I tried a solution by addingin **\s** to check empty space before the matching parameter but the issue I'm having is that when the @hasham is first in the paragraph, it doesn't get it because there is no empty space before trying to find a way. How can I simply select the independent words that fit my regex?

Comment: Duplicate of [regular expression to detect mentions but not detecting emails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23221732/3832970)

Comment: Dupe question was in php where lookbehind is universally supported but  olderJavascript platforms such as in Safari browser doesn't support lookbehind. But there might be other dupe targets for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with `\B` (reverse of word boundary):

```sh
/\B@(\w+)/g
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GPUtjD/3)

Comment: This matches if there's another punctuation character before `@`, like `foo(@hasham)`. That may be OK with the OP.

Answer (score 2):

Use a negative lookbehind.

```
/(?<!\S)@(\w+)/g
```

This matches `@` if it's not preceded by a non-whitespace character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/GPUtjD/2)